# export graphics on excel with quality

Tags: graphs, excel

I want to export graphs on excel to latex.

How I can do it ?  Save graph as image ?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88449/is-it-possible-to-put-ms-excel-graphs-into-a-latex-document?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel select the graph you want and save it as a pdf. Crop it with `pdfcrop` and include it in your TeX document with `\includegraphics`.

Comment: But I want to include as image.

Comment: It is an image. The answers to the related question @Torbjorn cites tell you in more detail how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Start here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/save-a-picture-as-a-jpg-gif-or-png-HA010337415.aspx Pick either .jpeg (.jpg) or .png as the file type for the image export. I've listed two since I've worked with both and they are common choices for TeX/LaTeX graphics inclusion. I'd recommend that you start with an empty document and gradually add too it as you climb the learning curve (note that there will be one...[note further that unlike mountain climbing where Class VI is an over hanging sand dune, there is no upper limit on this curve, excepting where it goes vertical...hehehe]) Pick a variety of situations you can anticipate the need to solve for. Single image one page. Double image one page. Double truck spread single image; und so weiter und so fort. Later on your way to being an old hand on this sort of thing you will have constructed and excellent document with solutions! Do not discard, share!!

Books you need:

- Guide to LaTeX 4th edition (or better but I think 4 is current). You should already have this, but if not, get one.
- LaTeX and Friends
- LaTeX:  Wikibooks Contributors

This site, the Wikibooks site and whatever Google suggests that looks interesting and/or pertinent.

Grotesquely general steps:

1. Read up on the typically one-liner that inserts an image, making sure you've included the necessary packages.
2. Do it.
3. Compile.
4. Repeat until bugs are found and crushed.
5. Add text in front of inclusion.
6. Do steps 3. and 4. again.
7. Add text after inclusion.
8. Do 6. again.
9. Modify the above to mimic your needs in the proposed document.
10. Continue to add other combinations.
11. Finish your document, returning to this document as new problems arise. Trust me, they will!
12. Publish. Profit! Pass the information on...

Answer (score 0):

Screendump, paste into paint or gimp or photoshop or whatever. Save as image. Then in latex document use `\includegraphics{...}`