# Insert tables and graph from Excel

Tags: floats, excel

I'm writing a report in LaTeX and I'm using excel to calculate, make graphs and tables. What would you recommend me to do to import it to latex?

I have tried taking print-screen and import as figures, but if the image scale isn't 100% it gets blurry and ugly.

I've been trying to export, print and save selected area as pdf. But no matter what I try, it exports with selected paper size. So it has a huge margin and I think it would take to much time to make a custom paper size for each figure.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The [Excel2LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex/) Add-in for Excel is what you're looking for here (for the table).

Comment: One can also save as a comma delimited file (csv) which can be read by pgfplotstable.

Comment: This question may help: [Comprehensive list of tools that simplify the generation of LaTeX tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49414/comprehensive-list-of-tools-that-simplify-the-generation-of-latex-tables)

Comment: See also [Is it possible to put MS Excel graphs into a LaTeX document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88449)

Comment: See this related question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246025/converting-word-or-excel-tables-to-latex?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

For tables you can use [Excel2Latex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex/) or [Csv2Latex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csv2latex). Excel to latex sometimes has a weird bug, where it inserts an invisible character. So I prefer the latter. Some editors also have an option to insert csv as a latex table.

For figures you can install [ASAP-utility](http://www.asap-utilities.com/) which will allow you to save your figures as a image (.png, .jpg or .esp). You can then insert them in your .tex file with `\includegraphics{}`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with tables some time ago and found a good solution without doing screenshots. First of all, I'm a linux user and thus have libreoffice. I go through these steps:

1. create the table in libreoffice and layout it as desired.
2. set printrange in a way that it only covers the desired part of my
   table and say that it should be on one page (size don't matter).
3. disable header and footer
4. save it as pdf. You get a pdf with your table and a white margin.
   lets say the name will be myTable.pdf.
5. run `pdfcrop` on the pdf: `pdfcrop myTable.pdf`
6. it will crop away all white margin and save it in myTable-crop.pdf
7. use the following latex code:

`\begin{table} [hbtp]
    \caption{Some caption}
    \label{tab:someLable}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=textheight,keepaspectratio]{myTable-crop}
\end{table}`

I found that this works best. No manual screenshots or whatever. Further it will not get pixeled if you zoom-in.

Comment: +1 fore being the more flexible solution to any type of original format.